# How to tell WebWorker to discard all but the latest postMessage data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I am using a WebWorker in a React component to filter a large array without blocking the main UI thread.

The WebWorker is triggered via `postMessage` in response to an `input` field.

When users type several characters into the `input` field, it seems that the WebWorker is processing all previous filters before processing the latest one.

Is there a way to tell the WebWorker to "forget about" all previous `postMessage`s except the last one?

Code:

```
handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    search: event.target.value
  })

  if (event.target.value.length > 2) {
    this.worker.postMessage({search: event.target.value})
    this.worker.onmessage = event => {
      this.setState({data: event.data})
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I have a basic implementation working. It throws away the active WebWorker (via `terminate`) every time the component is updated. I'm not sure if there is a better way.

```
constructor () {
  this.SearchWorker = require('worker-loader!../workers/search.js') // using worker-loader & webpack
  this.worker = new this.SearchWorker()
}

...

componentDidUpdate = (props, state) => {
  this.worker.terminate()
  this.worker = new this.SearchWorker()
  if (state.search !== this.state.search && this.state.search.length > 2) {
    this.worker.postMessage({search: this.state.search})
    this.worker.onmessage = event => {
      this.setState({data: event.data})
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why not a value to the last input, then compare it to see if the latest not equal that stored one. then after you can safely say its the latest.

Comment: @Caspain, I'll need to have some way of telling the WebWorker to `stop` doing any processing.  I'm not sure if there is a best practice around this.  So far all I'm seeing is the `terminate` method which requires a whole new WebWorker to be registered afterwards.

Comment: interesting i had very much the same problem. I used custom events to fire , to filter the old ones. Whenever this event is triggered only then the webWorker can start.

Comment: In my case, it is going to have been already started. I can, for instance, debounce the input, but that won't fully solve the problem since in some cases the WebWorker may run for longer than a normal debounce period, and it should be stopped.

Comment: I figured what about incorporating the delay  of direct debounce.

Comment: when does your worker starts ? conditions or normal, not making reference to length that is.

Comment: I've added a bit of code. This does stop the worker every time the component updates.  The WebWorker starts if the state property has changed, and if there are 3 or more characters in the input.  Not sure if there is a better way.